# Rewriting a Url Dynamically

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

You know how facebook has those urls like facebook.com/example that goes to the page for example? I want to do the same thing. I also want a script to check and see if that name has already been in use. Oh and if the user doesn't set a name then it just stays as the normal "more.php?id=4" page. Is this done in the htaccess file or what? Can you point me to any good links on the web that do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is very vague.

Have a google for apache content negotiation - if you fire a URL like....
   http://www.example.com/script.php/something/else

And 'script.php' is a file, then Apache will run script.php (but the full request URL will be available in the $_SERVER variables).

Alternatively, you could set your script as the 404 error handler - then whenever the webserver can't map the URL, it will call your script (again with the request URL in the $_SERVER vars).

While you can as 'the_' suggests use mod_rewrite - there are some obvious drawbacks here - effectively you need to map the request path (or part of it) into the query.

The other approach is to use a reverse proxy such as squid with a URL rewriter script - this could potentially connect to a database backend to get linear mappings.

Answer (score 0):

**url rewrite with .htaccess** you can search :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find info on [Rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)